# Git is it possible to revert unstaged files after a checkout

Tags: git

I accidently deleted a file which had many changes along with other modifications in others files.

Till this part I didn't commit any files.

On top of that I did a checkout to my previous commit.

Now all my changes are lost.

Is there a way I can recovered the changed for these un-committed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untracked files (when not stashed away with `git stash -u`) cannot be recovered by Git, because it did never know anything about them.

Comment: I knew I was screwed,anyways trying my luck.