# Git: Lost un-staged changes to file by checking out old version from previous commit?

Tags: git

Edit: I was able to get back the file by looking in the Team > Local History section of Eclipse. Still, this seems like strange behavior from git. It seems like destructive behavior should have a warning by default.

It seems I've allowed git to lull me into a false sense of security and have lost some work. But hopefully I'm misunderstanding something.

Situation:

I made a bunch of changes to a file "page_classes.py". I realized I had made a bad change and wanted to see how an old version looked, so I followed the directions from ([How do I restore files to previous states in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284/how-do-i-restore-files-to-previous-states-in-git)) and did

> git checkout c154ac3a6b1b723226c5b49ed6acaae614bed030 search_engine/page_classes.py

I saw what I wanted, then wanted to go back to what I was working on, so I did:

> git checkout lastfm search_engine/page_classes.py

(lastfm being the branch I was working on.)

Upsettingly, page_classes.py only reverted to its state as of my last commit, which was about an hour ago (i.e. before I made a bunch of changes.)

I neither committed nor staged the changes (because I've come to assume that git will never destroy work without at least a warning), but now it seems I cannot get my work back. This answer suggests as much: ([Git is it possible to revert unstaged files after a checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138193/git-is-it-possible-to-revert-unstaged-files-after-a-checkout))

Am I wrong that the work is gone? And if so, am I wrong to be surprised that git would overwrite and discard the new version of my file with no warning?

Comment: Haven't you ever noticed what it says when you type `git status`?  The stuff about using `git checkout -- file` to discard changes?  You just ran a variation of that exact command.  That's probably why they don't warn you.

Comment: Indeed it does say that. Too bad I never read it until now.